# On a possible proof for $p^k < m$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers, open-problem

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

If $\sigma(M)=2M$ and $M$ is odd, then $M$ is called an **odd perfect number** (hereinafter abbreviated as OPN).  It is currently unknown if there are any OPNs.  Euler proved that a hypothetical OPN, if one exists, must have the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$M = p^k m^2$$
where $p$ is the *special/Euler prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Dris conjectured in his [M. Sc.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) [thesis](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) that $p^k < m$ always holds for an OPN $M$ given in Eulerian form.

Consider the following "proof argument" for $p^k < m$:

Let $M = p^k m^2$ be an OPN given in Eulerian form.  Suppose that we have $m^2 < 5p^k$.

Then we have
$$\Bigg(m^2 < 5p^k\Bigg) \iff \Bigg(\frac{m^2}{p^k} < 5 \leq p^k\Bigg) \implies \Bigg(m^2 < p^{2k}\Bigg) \iff \Bigg(m < p^k\Bigg).$$

However, in the paper titled [*Improving the Chen and Chen result for odd perfect numbers*](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf), Broughan et al. show that $\sigma(m^2)/p^k \geq 315$.  This implies that
$$\frac{p^k}{m^2} < \frac{2}{315},$$
which contradicts
$$\frac{1}{5} < \frac{p^k}{m^2}.$$

Here is my question:

> **Does this "proof" indeed show that $p^k < m$ holds?  If it does not, can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?**

Comment: I think that it does not. You know that supposing that $m^2\lt 5p^k$ gives a contradiction. So, you have $m^2\geqslant 5p^k$ and "$m^2\lt 5p^k\implies m\lt p^k$" from which you cannot conclude $p^k\lt m$. (If you can show that "$m\lt p^k\implies m^2\lt 5p^k$", then you can say that $m\gt p^k$.)

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Please write your last comment as an actual answer so that I can upvote and then accept.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it does not.

You know that supposing that $m^2\lt 5p^k$ gives a contradiction. So, you have $m^2\geqslant 5p^k$ and "$m^2\lt 5p^k\implies m\lt p^k$" from which you cannot conclude $p^k\lt m$. (If you can show that "$m\lt p^k\implies m^2\lt 5p^k$", then you can say that $m\gt p^k$.)